# Change layout of Mac OS file selection dialog for home folder

Tags: macos, mac, finder

On my Mac, the file selection dialog for my home folder is irritatingly different from the way it looks for every other folder on my system- it compresses filenames to be almost uselessly small, and I can't sort the files, either. How can I change this?

## View used for home folder

[image: Current home folder view]

## View used for other folders

[image: View used for other folders]

Comment: In case you're interested, you can also drag the entire dialog larger, so all the columns have more room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finder and the file dialogs have had two separate sorting modes (arrange by and sort by) since 10.7. Those list headers are used when arrange by is not set to none, but you can set it back to none from this pop up menu:

[image]